# Failed to compile because configuration rules from eslintr are being overriden?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, eslint

I'm trying to compile my nextjs app but I keep getting errors that I snould be able to ignore:

```
> metaverse13@0.1.0 build
> next build && next export

warn  - The `app` dir is experimental. Please add `{experimental:{appDir: true}}` to your `next.config.js` to enable it
info  - Linting and checking validity of types ...warn  - The `app` dir is experimental. Please add `{experimental:{appDir: true}}` to your `next.config.js` to enable it
warn  - The Next.js plugin was not detected in your ESLint configuration. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#migrating-existing-config

Failed to compile.

./components/CustomTexts.jsx
3:45  Error: Strings must use singlequote.  quotes
4:1  Error: `framer-motion` import should occur before import of `../utils/motion`  import/order
6:47  Error: Multiple spaces found before '}'.  no-multi-spaces
8:3  Error: Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 2.  react/jsx-indent-props
9:3  Error: Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 2.  react/jsx-indent-props
13:43  Error: Trailing spaces not allowed.  no-trailing-spaces
14:7  Error: Expected indentation of 8 space characters but found 6.  react/jsx-indent-props
14:18  Error: A space is forbidden before closing bracket  react/jsx-tag-spacing
14:19  Error: The closing bracket must be aligned with the line containing the opening tag (expected column 7 on the next line)  react/jsx-closing-bracket-location
```

Here is the file it fails on first, CustomText.jsx:

```
'use client';

import { textContainer, textVariant2 } from "../utils/motion";
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

export const TypingText = ({ title, textStyles  }) => (
  <motion.p
  variants={textContainer}
  className={`font-normal text-[14px]
  text-secondary-white ${textStyles}`}
  >
    {Array.from(title).map((letter, index) => (
      <motion.span variants={textVariant2} 
      key={index} >
        {letter === ' ' ? '\u00A0' : letter}
      </motion.span>
    ))}
  </motion.p>
);

export const TitleText = ({ title, textStyles }) => (
  <motion.h2
    variants={textVariant2}
    initial="hidden"
    whileInView="show"
    className={`mt-[8px] font-bold md:text-[64px] text-[40px] text-white ${textStyles}`}
  >
    {title}
  </motion.h2>
);
```

Here is my eslintr.js file where I added 'jsx-quotes': 'off' at the bottom to try to ignore the single/double quotes errors:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'airbnb',
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
  ],
  rules: {
    'react/no-unescaped-entities': 0,
    'eslintreact/no-danger': 0,
    'react/jsx-max-props-per-line': 0,
    'react/jsx-first-prop-new-line': 0,
    'no-console': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control': 0,
    'no-nested-ternary': 0,
    'consistent-return': 0,
    'no-alert': 0,
    'react/jsx-no-constructed-context-values': 0,
    'import/extensions': 0,
    'react/prop-types': 0,
    'linebreak-style': 0,
    'react/state-in-constructor': 0,
    'import/prefer-default-export': 0,
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    'react/jsx-props-no-spreading': 'off',
    'jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions': 'off',
    'react/function-component-definition': [
      2,
      {
        namedComponents: 'arrow-function',
        unnamedComponents: 'arrow-function',
      },
    ],
    'max-len': [
      2,
      1050,
    ],
    'no-multiple-empty-lines': [
      'error',
      {
        max: 1,
        maxEOF: 1,
      },
    ],
    'no-underscore-dangle': [
      'error',
      {
        allow: [
          '_d',
          '_dh',
          '_h',
          '_id',
          '_m',
          '_n',
          '_t',
          '_text',
        ],
      },
    ],
    'object-curly-newline': 0,
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': 0,
    'react/jsx-one-expression-per-line': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/alt-text': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/no-autofocus': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions': 0,
    'react/no-array-index-key': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid': [
      'error',
      {
        components: [
          'Link',
        ],
        specialLink: [
          'to',
          'hrefLeft',
          'hrefRight',
        ],
        aspects: [
          'noHref',
          'invalidHref',
          'preferButton',
        ],
      },
    ],
    'jsx-quotes': 'off'
  },
};
```

And my eslintr.json file where I did the same thing:

```
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
  "rules": {
    "jsx-quotes": "off"
  }
}
```

I assume it has something to do with a configuration file but I'm not sure which ones.

Here is my next.config.js file

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: false,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

And finally my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "metaverse13",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build && next export",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.3",
    "framer-motion": "^7.6.7",
    "next": "13.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "eslint": "^8.27.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.10",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.19",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  }
}
```

I've also uploaded everything to a github repo [here](https://github.com/Mischa-bc/nextjs_template)

I tried adding 'jsx-quotes': ['error', 'prefer-double'] in the eslintr files but it didn't make a difference either.